# Как на удалённом сервере создать приложение на pyton?

Tags: python, perl

Никогда не имел делов с этим языком. На сервере есть папка **cgi-bin** и в ней файл **test.cgi** В нём приложение на perl, которое выводит тестовое сообщение.

```py
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";
print "<font color='blue'>\n";
print "<p><h3>It's a CGI script test</h3>\n";
print "</font>\n";

open (HTML,"../htdocs/test.html") or die "Can't open test.html: $!";
while (<HTML>) {
    print;
}

print "</body>\n";
print "</html>\n";
```

Когда создал файл с приложением на pyton:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
print("""Content-Type: text/plain

Hello, world!""")
```

, то появляется внутренняя ошибка сервера (500). Когда создал другой файл с таким же содержимым, как тот, в котором приложение на perl (test.cgi) - та же ошибка. Лог выводит такие ошибки:

```
[Mon Oct 03 14:24:53.100206 2022] [cgi:error] [pid 29098] [client 195.10.210.70:61857] AH01215: suexec failed: /virt/homes/opan/cgi-bin/rty.cgi
[Mon Oct 03 14:24:53.100518 2022] [cgi:error] [pid 29098] [client 195.10.210.70:61857] AH01215: (2)No such file or directory: exec failed (rty.cgi): /virt/homes/opan/cgi-bin/rty.cgi
[Mon Oct 03 14:24:53.100580 2022] [cgi:error] [pid 29098] [client 195.10.210.70:61857] End of script output before headers: rty.cgi
[Mon Oct 03 14:24:53.284731 2022] [core:info] [pid 29051] [client 195.10.210.70:61859] AH00128: File does not exist: /virt/homes/opan/htdocs/js/wow.min.js, referer: http://opan.ho.ua/cgi-bin/rty.cgi
[Mon Oct 03 14:24:53.285362 2022] [core:info] [pid 28989] [client 195.10.210.70:61860] AH00128: File does not exist: /virt/homes/opan/htdocs/js/ho-app.js, referer: http://opan.ho.ua/cgi-bin/rty.cgi
```

Как такое может быть, если файлы одинаковые? И ещё, как узнать, установлен ли на сервере интерпретатор pyton? В конечном итоге у меня цель загнать на сервер приложение на pyton, состоящее из многих папок и файлов. Опять же, не знаю, какой из этих файлов следует запускать. (setup.py вызывает ошибку внутренняя ошибка сервера 500)
Или помогите разобраться с установкой руководствуясь файлом readme:
[это его содержимое](https://github.com/mysynthesizer/index.hetemeel/blob/main/install.txt)
Там написано, что нужно выполнить команду:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/openai/whisper.git
```

А куда это вписать и где выполнить, я не знаю.
Буду очень рад, если поможете разобраться. За раннее спасибо.

В общем, объясните хотя бы, сайт на pyton - код должен быть на сайте, а интерпретатор pyton должен быть установленным на компьютере? Иначе почему учебник pyton начинается с того, что его нужно установить на компе?

Comment: «Как его запустить?» — просто перейти по адресу вида `http://сервер/cgi-bin/test.cgi` наверное?

Comment: Спасибо, получилось, столку было меня сбило то, что файлы сайта лежат в папке htdocs, но  в url эта папка не указывается, а сразу то, что в ней. А попробовать не додумался.

Comment: Всё равно непонятно. Попытался изменить содержимое файла test.cgi, но страница выводит старое содержимое. Очистка временных файлов не помогла.

Comment: А кэш в браузере не забыли почистить?

Comment: Да, чистил, вчера это не помогало, а сегодня проблеима исезла, стали отображаться изменения. Я переформулировал вопрос.

Comment: Если вы пытаетесь запустить какое-то существующее приложение на python, то с 99% вероятностью у вас ничего не получится, потому что CGI — это технология древних, которую в 2022 году уже никто не использует и современные приложения под неё не создают. Читайте в документации к интересующему вас приложению, как его запускать правильно. А для разбирательств с ошибками 500 читайте лог ошибок на сервере

Comment: «Как такое может быть, если файлы одинаковые?» — забыли добавить новому файлу бит разрешения на выполнение, наверное https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod

Comment: Chmod не помог. Пробовал вместо 644 сделать 755 и 777 - тот же результат.

Comment: Тогда читайте лог ошибок на сервере

Comment: Логи я опубликовал в вопросе. Там они ссылаются на несуществующие файлы. Плюс ещё дополнил вопрос.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139605/discussion-between--and-andreymal).